# Python str() function returns byte string

Tags: python

As far as I can tell, Python's str() function should by default return an UTF8 encoded string. However, unless I specifically specify encoding as UTF8, I get a byte string. Should I set a global somewhere to make the default active, or what am I doing wrong?
Python 3.10.6 on Fedora 36/XFCE

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Get the mount point of /dev/sd* mounts.
import subprocess

str2=subprocess.check_output(['cat', '/proc/mounts'])
mounts=str2.splitlines()

#print (mounts)

for x in range(len(mounts)):
    test = str(mounts[x], encoding="UTF8")
    if test[0:7] == '/dev/sd':
        print (test)
```

The above gives 'test' starting with /dev/sd/ , bit if I omit the encoding, the string starts with b'/dev/ .

Answer (score 3):

The Python 3 `str` always returns a Unicode string.  It is NOT an an encoded byte string.

The output of `subprocess` is a byte string.  If you do `str(b"1234")` the result is a Unicode string that happens to contain the b prefix: `"b'1234'"`  That's NOT a 4-byte byte string.  That's a 7-byte Unicode string.

When you do `str(b"1234", encoding="UTF8")` that converts the byte string to Unicode, exactly like saying `b"1234".decode('UTF8')`, which is the usual way to write what you have written.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that subprocess returns a naked byte string. Thanks for clarifying that. Is that specified somewhere? I did not see it after some searching.
I tested it by creating a directory name with an emoji in it on a JFS partition. Then indeed the output of a "ls" command shows the UTF8 byte string, if I use the str() on the output I get the proper emoji displayed.
I presume Python handles UTF16 as well (from NTFS).

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python3

# Test subprocess output for UTF8
import subprocess

# The directory (on JFS) contains names with UTF8 characters in them.
str1=subprocess.check_output(['ls', '/mnt/DataCommon/Test'])
print (str1)    # This prints the nakes byte string
str2=str(str1, encoding="UTF8")
print (str2) # This prints the formatted text.`